# How can i use the android studio software of 64 bit specification in 86 bit computer

Tags: android-studio-2.2

I installed android studio 64 bit on my PC with 86 bit specification. When I try to run android studio it is showing incompatible version. How can I make is useable??

Comment: You have a 32 bit x86 processor computer.

Comment: yes i have 32 bit x86 processor

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run 64 bit application on 32 bit computer.